# Unable to get controls data from child component in angular

Tags: angular

**main.component.html**

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #formData="ngForm" />


    <input type="text" ngModel name="firstName" />

    <div class="row" [ngSwitch]="type">

        <div *ngSwitchCase="'Employee'" class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
            <app-employee></app-employee>
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'Customer'" class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
            <app-customer></app-customer>
        </div>

    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**main.component.ts**

```js
@ViewChild('formData') formData: NgForm;

onSubmit(){
    console.log(formData.value);
}
```

**employee.component.html:**

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" ngModel name="Address"/>
```

Only able to get firstname value but not able to get any value from employee.component.html.

The scenario in this case is as per condition the template content would be changed and different template has it's own different controls.

Do I need to handle this condition in different way or the way I am using to read form data is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model object is each child components or pass the model object using @input from parent=>child. You can access the model object values in parent component on submit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to emit the data from the child component to the parent component and then populate the relevant formData with the emited value. You can do something like this:

employee.component.html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee" />
```

employee.component.ts:

```
@Output() onEmployeeEntered = new EventEmitter<string>();
employee: string;

employeeChanged = () => {
  this.onEmployeeEntered.emit(this.employee);
}
```

main.component.html:

```
<app-employee (onEmployeeEntered)="onEmployeeEntered(employee)"></app-employee>
```

main.component.ts:

```
onEmployeeEntered = (employee) => {
  // add the employee to form data 
  // let's say you have form data stored in form variable. 
  // You can do something like this.
  this.form.patchValue({
      'employee': employee
  });
}
```

Comment: form has near about 20-30 fields and I wanted that data back only when form gets submitted and not on change event.

Comment: You have 20-30 fields in app-employee component? I would then suggest that you get the employee component via ViewChild (https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/) and on submit get all the relevant data from that component (object of all the values) and store it in form data.

Comment: the `employee.component.html` contains only controls not which would then be wrapped inside form element in parent template. I tried ViewChild for `employee.component.html` but still unable to get data

Comment: Different examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563205/how-to-get-child-component-value-to-parent-component-in-angular2-what-is-the-be